# CW flag set after too many edits. Can a mod fix this question?

Tags: support, status-completed

I added a lot of [constructive edits to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19665491/328397) and flagged it for a mod to remove the CW link.

I've waited almost a week and there is no comment or response to this question.

I intend to put a bounty on the question, but before I do, I want to remove the CW flag (to make the bounty less expensive)

Comment: Since the vast majority of your edits are quite substantial, I went ahead and removed the wiki status for you.  Sorry for the delay (see Undo's answer below).

Answer (score 6):

It's completely within the scope of moderator abilities. However, you say you flagged with a custom flag (the right thing to do), and you've been waiting a week. Here's an explanatory image:

[image]

[Yours are in the 'other' category.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204062/215468)

Edit: Looks like Bill removed the CW for you.

Comment: What a massive queue!  If/when I get achieve such a status I'll pitch in and help.

Comment: @makerofthings7 do you know what it takes to be a diamond mod? Unless you do, you probably don't qualify.

Comment: @JanDvorak ... I was confusing that with 10K rep... got it.

Comment: @Jan He's 15k on Sec.SE... So he probably does.

Comment: @Undo in which case I welcome our upcoming big brother and overlord.

Comment: "Your flag is important to us. Please hold for the next available moderator."